# How to force user to use native android soft keyboard instead of swiftkey on my application?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

I want to make sure no other than native android soft keyboard is used on my application such as swiftkey. Is there a way to specify which soft keyboard will user use for input?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: because swiftkey may keep passwords, username of my user and I don't want to let that happen.